# Имена файлов asset добавить в ListView

Tags: android, listview, массивы

Есть необходимость в фрагменте в onCreateView создать ListView, который будет брать свои значения из определенной папки в директории assets.
У меня есть часть кода для создания ListView.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код для импорта имен файлов из assets в `String[]`.

Огромная благодарность!

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceBundle) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type_one, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_TypeOne);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.list_item,
                names);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить список файлов из корня assets:

```
  AssetManager aMan = context.getAssets();
  String[] filelist = aMan.list("");
```

Если нужны поддиректории, то рекурсивно прогонять, например.

Comment: Спасибо!
Подскажите еще один момент:
как в названии убрать расширение файла, скажем .txt?

Comment: Прогнать список и заменить строки регуляркой или обычными операциями для работы со строками.

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста?